# Как возвращать из функции массив вместе со строкой?

Tags: php, массивы, строки, form

Есть решение задачи:

```
<form action="" method="GET">
    <label for="a">Введите число 1: <input type="text" name="number[]" id="a"></label>
    <label for="b">Введите число 2: <input type="text" name="number[]" id="b"></label>
    <input type="submit" value="Вычислить">
</form>

<?php
    error_reporting(E_ALL);

    print_r(getCommonFactors('number'));
    function getCommonFactors($inputNumber) {
        if (!empty($_REQUEST)) {
            $number = $_REQUEST[$inputNumber];
            $dividers = [];
            for ($i = 2; $i < $number[0]; $i++) {
                if ($number[0] % $i == 0) {
                    $dividers[] = $i;
                }
            }

            $commonFactors = [];
            foreach ($dividers as $elem) {
                if ($number[1] % $elem == 0) {
                    $commonFactors[] = $elem;
                }
            }
            return 'Делители: ' . $commonFactors;
        }
    }

?>
```

Хотел вывести типа: Делители: // и здесь элементы массива;

Но выдает ошибку: Array to string Conversation. Понимаю в чем проблема. Пытался сделать вот так:

```
echo "Делители:" . print_r(getCommonFactors('number');
```

Но получился вот такой ответ:

```
Array ( [0] => 3 ) Делители:1
```

Вопрос как можно сделать, например так:

```
Делители: 3
```

Comment: Функция implode.

Comment: Спасибо, и как я не додумался!